# Using Appium to automate Genymotion Cloud Virtual Device

Tags: appium, genymotion

I tried to get information online but could not get a proper answer to my question. I want to be able to automate Native app installed on a Emulator on GenyMotion Cloud using Appium? If yes how can this be done. I want to be able to run the scripts on my local by accessing the Emulator on the cloud.

I have seen articles about Appium + GenyMotion Desktop version only so far.

Answer (score 1):

Genymotion devices behave like standard Android devices so you can connect to them through ADB and run your tests with Appium.

You can automate the creation and the start of devices using Genymotion's command line tool, [GMTool](https://docs.genymotion.com/Content/04_Tools/GMTool/GMTool.htm).

Comment: Thanks. I need to check if this solves my requirement.